# Unpacking Tuple in Dictionary Value

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, tuples, iterable-unpacking

i have a tuple of suspects those suspects exist in dictionary and in the dictionary
i have a tuple value

i try to unpacking the values to varibles

```
suspects = (
 {'name': 'Anne', 'evidences': ('derringer', 'Caesarea')},
 {'name': 'Taotao', 'evidences': ('derringer', 'Petersen House')},
 {'name': 'Pilpelet', 'evidences': ('Master Sword', 'Hyrule')},
 )
for t in suspects:
   for name, weapon,location in t.items():
```

there i got stacked.
i try to run python tutor to see a feeback of my faults,
but i can't understand  how can i extract the specific value
with unpacking solution

for examp solution:
Name = Anne ,  Weapon = Derringer  , Location = Caesarea

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:

```
suspects = (
 {'name': 'Anne', 'evidences': ('derringer', 'Caesarea')},
 {'name': 'Taotao', 'evidences': ('derringer', 'Petersen House')},
 {'name': 'Pilpelet', 'evidences': ('Master Sword', 'Hyrule')},
 )
for t in suspects:
    name = t['name']
    weapon, location = t['evidences']
    print(name, weapon, location)
```

Output:

```
Anne derringer Caesarea
Taotao derringer Petersen House
Pilpelet Master Sword Hyrule
```

EDIT: If you *must* unpack twice, here's an uglier way to do it that *does* unpack twice (key, value) and (weapon, location) :

```
suspects = (
 {'name': 'Anne', 'evidences': ('derringer', 'Caesarea')},
 {'name': 'Taotao', 'evidences': ('derringer', 'Petersen House')},
 {'name': 'Pilpelet', 'evidences': ('Master Sword', 'Hyrule')},
 )
for t in suspects:
    name = None
    weapon = None
    location = None
    for key, value in t.items():
       if key == "name":
          name = value
       elif key == "evidences":
           weapon, location = value
    print(name, weapon, location)
```

Comment: Or even `name, (weapon, location) = t['name'], t['evidences']` but I think yours is clearer :)

Comment: my mission is to use at least twice in unpacking method to solve this

Answer (score 0):

This would be the way to do it:

```
for t in suspects:
    weapon, location = t["evidences"]
    print(f"Name: {t['name']} Weapon: {weapon} Location: {location}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure isn't conducive to what you're trying to do exactly. If there's a specific reason why you want to keep this particular structure, then use the answers provided. If, however, you're open to using a different data structure:

```py
suspects = {"Anne": ("derringer", "Caesarea"),
            "Taotao": ("derringer", "Petersen House"),
            "Pilpelet": ("Master Sword", "Hyrule")}

for name, (weapon, location) in suspects.items():
    print(name, weapon, location)
```

Output:

```
Anne derringer Caesarea
Taotao derringer Petersen House
Pilpelet Master Sword Hyrule
```

Comment: its a part from mission that i have to solve this with unpcaking method in this data structure i know that if i change the data structure its woukd be very comfort to solve ... thank for your answer